# FOS Userbundle - declare own userID field

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have installed the FOS UserBundle.

The problem is: the "id" field of my User-Table is called userID.

I can't change it bc of other Tables and Programming that is dependent on the userID field.

If i try to login, i get an error:

```
Unrecognized field: id
```

The problem seems to lie in the call for the id field:

```
UserManager ->findUserBy (array('id' => 1))
```

Can I somehow override FOS UserBundle so that the findby() method transfers id to userID?
Or do i get it totally wrong and have to do it another way?

Answer (score 0):

Field names in the entity don't have to be identical to the field names in your sql table. So you can use "id" as field in your doctrine entity and map it to a "userID" field in your sql table.

If you are using Doctrine annotations for your user entity like in the FOSUserBundle documentation, this could do the trick:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="userID", type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
```

I haven't tested it and there is a chance that it doesn't work, because the id field is always a bit "special", but it may be worth a try.

Comment: that was a great idea :)
sadly not the solution - FOS UserBundle still can't find the id field. :/

Answer (score 0):

Generate your own UseBundle  and add in define the entity something like this.

```
  <?php

  namespace Demo\UserBundle\Entity;

  use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
  use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

  /**
   * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Sciviz\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
   * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
  */
  class User extends BaseUser {

  /**
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
   protected $id;

  /** @ORM\Column(name="first_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $first_name;
     ..................
```

Also see this tutorial 
http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/fosuserbundle-ftw

Comment: I don't have a field $id - my field is called $userID - i can add the id field to the table but that field will not have the user id.

I don't build it from scratch - the database is already in place and many other modules are dependent on the userID field - so I can't simply change that.

Answer (score 0):

your column name "USER_ID" can be case sensitive.

```
 /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="user-table")
     */
    class User extends BaseUser
    {
        /**
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="USER_ID")
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
        protected $id;

    }
```